# Good reference for Fourier Analysis

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Would you please indicate a good reference about Fourier analysis (Fourier series, convergence theorems: pointwise, uniform convergence, $L^2-$convergence...etc)? It should concern the organisation of a course for the undergraduate level.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&safe=active&ssui=on#safe=active&q=fourier+series+books

Comment: It's not a very good choice ..

Comment: As a reference,not an introductory text,you might have a look at the old classic  Trigonometric Series  by Carslaw.

Comment: would you please post an accessible link ?

Comment: @user254665 Did you mean Zygmund?

Comment: Vretblad's Fourier Analysis and its Applications contains a lot for a reader without knowledge of the Lebesgue integral. However I found it a bit boring. I'm currently reading Fourier Series and Integrals by H. Dym and H. P. McKean. So far an excellent book. Should be accessible for undergrads.

Comment: Zygmund : Trigonometric Series. Yes.But I was also thinking of Carslaw's book which I think was titled Fourier Series.

Comment: @LionelRicci I think this is what I'm looking for. Would please give an accessible link ?

Comment: @A.MONET [here's one](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0122264517/ref=s9_simh_gw_g14_i2_r?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=desktop-1&pf_rd_r=1QFKKBE9E1SD1K3MM31D&pf_rd_t=36701&pf_rd_p=2079475242&pf_rd_i=desktop)

Comment: So I have to buy it :D

Comment: Well maybe there's some library that is generous... If you think the price if hefty I agree.

Comment: Unfortunately yes. [here is something related](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~nati/PAPERS/uw/root.pdf)

Comment: *Fourier Series and Boundary Value Problems* Brown and Churchill.